# Flask Pagination Error - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'paginate'

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I'm trying to paginate some results from SQLite database in my `@app.route` but I'm getting this error

```
schools = db.execute("SELECT * FROM schools ORDER BY id").paginate(page, pages, error_out=False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'paginate'.
```

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={"page": 1})
@app.route('/search/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search(page):
    if request.method == "GET":
        page = page
        pages = 10
        schools = db.execute("SELECT * FROM schools ORDER BY id").paginate(page, pages, error_out=False)
        return render_template("search.html", schools=schools)
```

Is there another way I can implement pagination?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm currently having the same issue using flask-sqlalchemy even with a direct example from the current docs. Quite frustrating lol